# isMethod('POST') doesn't work properly on server

Tags: php, post, symfony-1.4

I'm dealing with a strange situation ! Indeed, I'm working on a SSO connexion, my code works locally, but doesn't work on my preprod server !

After several debug attempt, I found that my problem is at the line

```
if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
```

So, I don't get, why this works totally fine locally, but not online !

My php versions are the same locally and online, I'm using [PostMan](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/wiki) to simulate the post method for identification.

Comment: is it Symfony 2.x or 1.4? These are two completely different frameworks

Comment: Yap, sorry, this is symfony 1.4 ! The tag for symfony 2.x came out of nowhere ..

Comment: did you use Symfony CRUD generator ? And does this happen on an edit action ? If it does, pay attention to the controller generated and check that the CRUD generator did not set the form method to "PUT". That's what Symfony 2 CRUD generator does, for editAction.

Comment: What is your 404 handler (`ErrorDocument 404` for apache)? Both apache and nginx will turn POST requests to missing pages to GET request.

Comment: I've found my problem, this was my hoster that had some issue that made my redirect after POST not working..

So when I loaded my page, I treated correctly my data, but then , a reload of the page happened, but with the POST data missing, that's why it couldn't accept it as a POST method since there weren't any data.

This is fixed, thank you for your time. If you wish more informations (for those who are in same position as I was), I can post a detailed resume later.